# Regex with only union, concat, *, +, and epsilon

Tags: regex

There are two questions I can't just get down for all cases. The language used in both questions is {a, b, c}

> 1. All strings of a’s, b’s, and c’s that contain no a’s immediately following any b’s

So far I have `(a|c|b(bc+|b*c))*` which works in some cases but when ending on a b requires two bs to be in a row which I'm not sure how to workaround.

> 2. All strings of a’s, b’s, and c’s that do not contain more than 2 b’s and 2 a’s.

I know this has to be something of the format `c*(a|b)c*(a|b)c*` ... but I'm not sure how to "count" the a's vs the b's as I know counting in regex with these symbols is impossible.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be helpful, even if it requires symbols outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Casually, this looks like the answer to 1: `(a|b(?!a)|c)*` but it's probably language theory you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To allow for `b`'s at the end append `b*`.

   ```
   (a|c|b(bc+|b*c))*b*
   ```

   You could simplify this some. The `+` in `bc+` isn't needed since `c`'s after the first are already covered by the `|c|` possibility. That leaves `b(bc|b*c)`, which can be simplified to `b(b*c)`, which in turn reduces to `b+c`. End result:

   ```
   (a|b+c|c)*b*
   ```
2. An inelegant answer is to list out all the arrangements of 2 a's and 2 b's.

   ```
   aabb|abab|abba|baab|baba|bbaa
   ```

   Add `?`'s so they're all optional, fulfilling the "up to 2" requirement. You can pretend each `x?` is really `(x|ε)`.

   ```
   a?a?b?b?|a?b?a?b?|a?b?b?a?|b?b?a?a?|b?a?b?a?|b?a?a?b?
   ```

   Then slap `c*`'s all over the place.

   ```
   c*a?c*a?c*b?c*b?c*|c*a?c*b?c*a?c*b?c*|c*a?c*b?c*b?c*a?c*|
   c*b?c*b?c*a?c*a?c*|c*b?c*a?c*b?c*a?c*|c*b?c*a?c*a?c*b?c*
   ```

   Boy am I not proud of that answer.

Comment: Ahh, I was so close on the first one, but that makes complete sense now.

Comment: The second one as well, after a second opinion makes sense as well. Thanks again!

Comment: @Minnal I've rewritten the second answer. I was originally thinking the problem is to have no more than 2 a's and b's *combined*. A commenter (whose name I lost after they deleted their comments--sorry, commenter!) pointed out that that's an incorrect reading of the question.